# CSS3 Trigger mouseover state on document ready

Tags: jquery, html, css, triggers, mouseover

I know, there are plenty of posts relating to this topic, but for some reasons I wasn't able to apply the answers to my case and hope someone can help me with that in particular.

Basically, I want my menu to blink once in the style of the navigation class when entering the page. (Like you would hover the links once) I thought it would be possible to do it with this snippet

```
    $(function () {
        $(".navigation a").mouseover();
    });
```

Unfortunately nothing happens...
Here my [code](http://jsfiddle.net/vkr1so7q/)

I appreciate your help.

Cheers
Eric

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to give the element time to transition.
What I've done is added another selector to your `.navigation a:hover` selector for `.navigation a.active`, then I toggle that class with a delay so that it can be visible for a little bit of time:

```js
$(function() {
  $(".navigation a").addClass('active');
  setTimeout(function() {
    $(".navigation a").removeClass('active');
  }, 150);
});
```

```css
body {
  background-color: black;
}
/*Navigation formatting*/

.navigation {
  text-decoration: none;
  list-style: none;
  text-align: center;
  padding-top: 50px;
  border-top: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
  border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
  font-size: 38px;
  color: white;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.7s ease;
  transition: all 0.7s ease;
}
.navigation ul {
  padding-left: 0;
}
.navigation li {
  display: inline;
  padding-left: 3em;
}
li:first-child {
  /*padding vom ersten element des menues entfernen*/
  padding-left: 0;
}
.navigation a {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 10px;
}
.navigation a.active,
.navigation a:hover {
  color: #bd4832;
  text-shadow: 0px 0 15px #fff;
  border: 1px;
  text-decoration: none;
  border-top: 1px solid #fffad5;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #fffad5;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="home" class="container-fluid">
  <nav class="navigation">
    <ul>
      <li><a class="navigation" href="#me">About</a>
      </li>
      <li><a class="navigation" href="#portfolio">Portfolio</a>
      </li>
      <li><a class="navigation" href="#contact">Contact</a>
      </li>
      <li><a class="navigation" href="#blog">Travelblog</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/vkr1so7q/4/